# click function for retrieving div

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i retrieve find out which button click is from which div.
Basically i have multiple div

```
<div id="rare1">
<input type=button value="OK" id=btn>
</div>
<div id="rare2">
<input type=button value="OK" id=btn>
</div>
<div id="rare3">
<input type=button value="OK" id=btn>
</div>
```

i have a function

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#rare"+i+" #btn").attr("disabled", "true");
}
```

this way i can disable the latest button being added.
how can i select which ever button is click on different div id and select the correct btn to disable?

**so sorry forget to add something i want to retrieve the div id that clicked the button too.**

Comment: you should never have duplicate id, we want every individual object a unique entity in code world B-) `id=btn` that is

Comment: You should be using `.prop('disabled', true)` and IDs need to be unique.

Comment: so sorry forget to add something i want to retrieve the div id that clicked the button too.

Comment: btw the reason y btn having duplicated id is because all the div is being load using .load function from other html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `id` must be uniqe per element per page. Currently you have `btn` for each button, use a class instead eg `class="btn"` and then modify your code like this:

```
<div id="rare1">
   <input type=button value="OK" class=btn>
</div>
<div id="rare2">
   <input type=button value="OK" class=btn>
</div>
<div id="rare3">
   <input type=button value="OK" class=btn>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
}
```

To get current clicked button, use `$(this)` as shown in code above.

---

### Update Based On Comments

To get parent div id, use:

```
$(this).parent().attr('id')
```

So:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var parentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: Also, use `.prop('disabled', true)` - or simply `this.disabled = true`

Comment: so sorry forget to add something i want to retrieve the div id that clicked the button too.

Comment: @user1397840 alert($(this).parent().attr('id')); //getting the parent id ,put it inside that click function

Comment: @user1397840: Use `$(this).parent().attr('id')` or `$(this).closest('div').attr('id')` as pointed out by uberooluk too.

Comment: Great its working. just that it's not working in my iframe. i need to figure how it works thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Id is for unique buttons give it class

```
<div id="rare1">
<input type=button value="OK" class="btn">
</div>
<div id="rare2">
<input type=button value="OK" class="btn">
</div>
<div id="rare3">
<input type=button value="OK" class="btn">
</div>

$(".btn").click(function(){

    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
});
```

Comment: so sorry forget to add something i want to retrieve the div id that clicked the button too.

Comment: alert($(this).parent().attr('id')); //getting the parent id

Answer (score 1):

You can select the clicked button by using the 'this' var.

`$("#btn").click(function(){
 $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
}`

Comment: so sorry forget to add something i want to retrieve the div id that clicked the button too.